# No data is sent from form to action

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using DataTables.js in an ASP.NET MVC application. I want to handle things on the server in an action but there seems to be no data sent from the form in the view to the action. I have built some code to test this from this example: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-datatables-grid-with-asp-net-mvc/

I have a simple view:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <br />
      <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
        <table id="demoGrid" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>CustomerID</th>
              <th>CompanyName</th>
              <th>ContactName</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The DataTable is set up like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#demoGrid").DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "filter": true,
    "orderMulti": false,
    "pageLength": 5,
    "ajax": {
      "url": "/MOF2/Demo/LoadData",
      "type": "POST",
      "datatype": "json"
    }
  });
});
```

The action does not contain much yet:

```
public ActionResult LoadData()
{
  var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
  var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
  var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
  return View();
}
```

After reading a bit on https://datatables.net/ and the example mentioned above i expected to be able to get some values here. For instance I expected `length` to be 5. I get nothing though. For instance `Request.Form.GetValues("length")` is null. If i check `Request.Form.AllKeys` i get an empty string. What can cause this? What is needed for form data to be sent by JavaScript and Ajax so it can be read by `Request.Form.GetValues()`?

Note: I have downloaded an example project mentioned in a comment to the example above and it works as expected. I have also stripped away most of the code not used in the example from that project and it still works. I can't really find the difference between the example project and my project though. The example project can be found here: https://github.com/saineshwar/DataTablesGridExample

Comment: is this a form post or data is in request body

Comment: @Shantanu I'm not entirely sure what that means and how to answer that question.

Comment: Well when you click on next (paging) do you get any values then?

Comment: @HastaTamang No. I believe that I should get values both immediately when the page is loaded and when I change something in the page, like how many rows arr displayed or sort order.

In the example project that I mention in the question I get values both when the page is loaded and when i change something in the page.

My gut feeling tells mi that my I need to change some kine of setting in order for form data to be included when the ajax request is made. I can't figure out what though.

Comment: Could you verify if your view makes a form request  to your action method, in the networks tab? Also check if you have any console errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of mine found out the solution. The URL in the ajax object should be changed so that it uses `@Url.Action()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#demoGrid").DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "filter": true,
    "orderMulti": false,
    "pageLength": 5,
    "ajax": {
      "url": "@Url.Action("LoadData", "Demo")",
      "type": "POST",
      "datatype": "json"
    }
  });
});
```

The project uses [Cookie less ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa479314(v=msdn.10)) and that means, among other things, that the session id is stored in the URL. When I pointed out the URL directly the session got lost and with it the form data.

I'm not entirely sure how session, session id and form data exactly ties together here but using  `@Url.Action()` seems to be the solution in my case.

I'm answering my own question here so others who run into the same problem can see how it was solved for me.

Comment: So instead of `/MOF2/Demo/LoadData` your url should have been `/Demo/LoadData`.

Comment: @HastaTamang Actually it should have been something like this: `/(S(jv3otbn3ix5n3g22vby4loc4))/MOF2/Production/Nesting`. The random character string before /MOF2 is the session ID which is stored in the URL instead of a cookie. Since this is impossible to predict I can use `@Url.Action()` which knows the session ID and includes it to make a complete URL.